# SwiftMailerBundle : [Semantical Error] with getMapType() method

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm working on a Symfony2 project. I have to build a webservice which is reached by mobile devices. The webservice send email to new devices using **SwiftmailerBundlle**.

Swiftmailer is also the mail sender for the entire project. It works perfectly on every bundles except my webservice.
When the webservice **tries to send an email with Swiftmailer, I always get a 500 type error**. The strangest part is that the mail is sent despite the 500 error !!

Here is the error I get :

"[Semantical Error] The annotation \"@int\" in method Swift_CharacterReader_Utf8Reader::getMapType() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a \"use\" statement for this annotation?"

And the method in the SwifMailerBundle :

class Swift_CharacterReader_Utf8Reader implements Swift_CharacterReader 
{

```
/**
* Returns mapType
* @int mapType
*/
public function getMapType()
{
    return self::MAP_TYPE_POSITIONS;
}
}
```

Here is my code in a class used by my webservice :

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject($subject)
->setFrom('test@exemple.com')
->setTo('test@exemple.com')
->setBody("Test")
;

$this->mailer->send($message);
```

SwiftMailerBundle version=4.1.3

This is the way to implement Swiftmailer in every docs I've read. Do you guys see what my problem could be ?
Is there a mistake in the bundle ? Is my implementation wrong ?

I'm quite confused and thank you in advance for your time.

Elodie.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the @int comment it's messing up symfony's annotation reader